# Hotkey in Windows context menu

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys, context-menu

I've added (in registry) an 'Open in Notepad++' item to my context menu in Windows 8 (for some reason, it is not added during the instalation).

I used the ampersand (&) to assign a hotkey, like this:

```
Edit with &Notepad++
```

and n is now indeed underlined in my context menu, but the hotkey doesn't work (even if I choose a hotkey that is not used by any other application). How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you press 'n'? Does the menu item get highlighted?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If I choose unused letter, context menu closes when I press hotkey. If I choose letter that is used by one other item, that item's command gets called, and if I choose letter used by multiple items, 'cursor' circulates between those items, but skips Notepad++ item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Hotkey is always the letter that item's title starts with. Ampersand makes the letter underlined, but it has no other effect.

If the title is 'Edit with Notepad++', then hotkey is 'e', and if I want 'n' to be hotkey, I need to rename it to 'N Edit with Notepad++' or 'Notepad++', and I don't need an ampersand.

This doesn't seem like a logic behaviour, it might be a bug, but that is how it works.

Comment: Yes, I know that it **shouldn't** be that way, but it appears to be in my case. I added:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT>*>shell>Edit with &Notepad++>command>c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1

Also, afterwards I noticed that in Windows Explorer there is (added by installation) an 'Edit with Notepad++' item, but it isn't present in Total Commander, where I experienced this situation.

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected, you added it wrong (hotkey doesn't work your way for me either). See my answer which works in Win Explorer. If Total Commander or other file manager behaves in a non-standard manner, that's its problem.

Comment: You are correct, this is quite annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Save the following as a .REG file and import into your registry to add an entry for Notepad++ to the context menu of all files:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\np]
@="Edit &with Notepad++"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\np\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe \"%1\""
```

Save the following as a .REG file and import into your registry to add an entry for Notepad++ to the context menu of .TXT files only:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\np]
@="Edit &with Notepad++"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\np\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe \"%1\""
```

You can also use a program such as [**FileTypesMan**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) if you don't like to edit the registry manually.

Result:

[image: 1]