# Possible to change/edit which letters are underlined in context-menus?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, context-menu

I want to change some of the underlined letters for quick-selecting context menu entries, particularly, for Firefox (but knowing how to do so for general Windows 7 context menus would be great, too).

For example, if I select some text on a page and right-click, the entry for searching Google has its first "S" underlined. I'm wondering where I might go to edit/change/add these.

Comment: Not sure about firefox but [this link](http://superuser.com/a/564409/161391) might help on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/). Simply install the add-on, restart Firefox, open the menu containing the menuitem you'd like to change, click the small icon you'll now find in the lower-right corner of all menus, click the wrench icon beside your menuitem, and enter a new value for "Access Key".